# Doctrine 2 @Id @GeneratedValue issue

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

So even though I have resolved my own issue, what I would like to know is if I did it the right way or not?

I'm using the code from the Doctrine docs to insert a new record into the database my code looks like this and it is looping over as xlsx being process by PHPExcel.

I have this set for an Entity

```
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @Column(name="uploaduserid", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @Id
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;
```

--

```
 $user = new \Uploaduserdetails();
 $user->id = 0;
 $user->userid = $item->userid;
 $user->email = $cells['A'];
 $user->firstname = $cells['B'];
 $user->lastname = $cells['C'];
 $user->street = $cells['D'];
 $user->city = $cells['E'];
 $user->state = $cells['F'];
 $user->zip = $cells['G'];
 $user->mobile = $cells['H'];

 $entityManager->persist($user);
 $entityManager->flush();
```

Now, even though this works and the record appears in the database (MariaDB), the bit that is giving me trouble and I know this seems a little over kill but its this

```
$user->id = 0;
```

According to the docs http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html (shown below) this should not need to be set. Set the name, persist the object and flush. But in my case I get the fatal error below if I don't set the value of id to something numeric. The result in the DB is a unique number as expected and not the value set, which is great. I've also tried setting the generation strategy to "AUTO", leaving it out and just leaving it at @GeneratedValue. All generate the same error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\ORMException' with message 'Entity of type Uploaduserdetails is missing an assigned ID for field 'id'. The identifier generation strategy for this entity requires the ID field to be populated before EntityManager#persist() is called.

```
<?php
// src/Product.php
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="products")
 **/
class Product
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
    protected $id;
    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    protected $name;

    // .. (other code)
}
```

--

```
<?php
// create_product.php
require_once "bootstrap.php";

$newProductName = $argv[1];

$product = new Product();
$product->setName($newProductName);

$entityManager->persist($product);
$entityManager->flush();

echo "Created Product with ID " . $product->getId() . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to my own question.

You should only use @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY") on the primary key where your auto generating numbers or a sequence.